# Setting up Angular 2 to work on MAMP

Tags: angular, mamp

I've used the Angular 2 Cli to create the app folder structure and dependencies but I can't get it to work when I call the app in browser using a local install of mamp.

It seems the CLI is geared towards a NodeJs server. So, what do I have to change to make it work with mamp?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault. It was the  tag that was the issue. I've set the correct path  on it and all works fine